# bindParameter function with variadic templates in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, bind, inference

I'm trying to write a simple function to convert a std::function<> object while binding the last parameter(s). That's what I've got:

```cpp
template<typename R, typename Bind, typename ...Args> std::function<R (Args...)> bindParameter (std::function<R (Args..., Bind)> f, Bind b)
{
    return [f, b] (Args... args) -> R { return f (args..., b); };
}
```

And that's how I'd like to use it:

```cpp
int blub (int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}

// ...

int main ()
{
    std::function<int (int, int)> f1 (blub);

    // doesn't work
    std::function<int (int)> f2 = bindParameter (f1, 21);

    // works
    std::function<int (int)> f3 = bindParameter<int, int, int> (f1, 21);

    return f2 (2);
}
```

... so that in this example the main function should return 42. The problem is, that gcc (4.6) doesn't seem to infer the types of the template parameters correctly, the first version produces the following errors:

```cpp
test.cpp:35:58: error: no matching function for call to 'bindParameter(std::function<int(int, int)>&, int)'
test.cpp:35:58: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:21:82: note: template<class R, class Bind, class ... Args> std::function<R(Args ...)> bindParameter(std::function<R(Args ..., Bind)>, Bind)
```

But in my opinion the parameters are obvious. Or is this kind of type inference not covered by the standard or not yet implemented in gcc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `std::function` as a deduced parameter of a function template. Deduction can't work in this fashion as there are no rules to match `int(*)(int, int)` to `std::function<int(int, int)>`. (Consider also that for *any* `std::function<Signature>` there is a constructor accepting `int(*)(int, int)`, even if in most cases this results in an error when instantiated.)

It's problematic to detect the signature of functor in the general case. Even KennyTM's solution has limitations: it detects the signature of monomorphic functors and function-like things, but won't work for polymorphic functors (e.g. with overloaded `operator()`) or functors with surrogate call functions (even in the monomorphic case).

It is however possible to completely sidestep the issue of detecting the signature thanks to `decltype` (or equivalently, `std::result_of`), and I would recommend doing so. Hence, a variant on KennyTM's answer:

```
template<typename Functor, typename Bound>
struct bind_last_type {
    Functor functor;
    Bound bound;

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args)
    -> typename std::result_of<Functor&(Args..., Bound)>::type
    // equivalent:
    // -> decltype( functor(std::forward<Args>(args)..., std::move(bound)) )
    { return functor(std::forward<Args>(args)..., std::move(bound)); }
};

template<typename Functor, typename Bound>
bind_last_type<
    typename std::decay<Functor>::type
    , typename std::decay<Bound>::type
>
bind_last(Functor&& functor, Bound&& bound)
{ return { std::forward<Functor>(functor), std::forward<Bound>(bound) }; }
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that the constructor of any std::function can take any callable with another signature (seems to throw errors internally...). This also makes my question to KennyTM spare.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the inference, but it works if I just define a templated function object.

```
template <typename FType, typename LastArgType>
struct BindLastHelper
{
    FType _f;
    LastArgType _last_arg;

    template <typename... Args>
    typename utils::function_traits<FType>::result_type
        operator()(Args&&... args) const
    {
        return _f(std::forward<Args>(args)..., _last_arg);
    }
};

template<typename FType, typename LastArgType>
BindLastHelper<FType, LastArgType> bindParameter (FType f, LastArgType b)
{
    return BindLastHelper<FType, LastArgType>{f, b};
}
```

Note:

- `utils::function_traits` is taken from https://github.com/kennytm/utils/blob/master/traits.hpp. `std::result_of` cannot be used because you are not passing a function pointer.
- Proof of concept: http://ideone.com/ux7YY (here for simplicity I just redefined `result_of`.)

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! But is it possible to convert the return value of `bindParameter` (via an extra helper function or something) so that I can write something like `auto f3 = bindParameterAnotherHelper (f2, int);` so that `f3` becomes an object of type `std::function<int (int)>` automatically?